# How to run retrofit ground wire to a new (4-wire 50A) receptacle?

Tags: electrical, wiring, 240v, range

I will be adding a ground to an existing 3-wire setup in oder to make it safe and code-complaint.
Will the new bare **Cu** ground wire use the same receptacle knockout (bottom) as the **Al** jacketed 3-wire, or will it have to be clamped from the back via the other knockout?

[image]

[image]
Is it OK to have exposed bare ground (4th-wire) for a short run behind/under the range?
[image]

Comment: I have a feeling there will be only 1 clamp provided per receptacle.What type of clamp do I need to get for a bare #8 or #6 ground wire