# How to retrofit this circuit to be able to run a bare ground splice to another appliance?

Tags: electrical, water-heater, waterproofing, copper, ground

[image]

I'm adding a #8AWG **bare** ground in order to retrofit a 3-wire **range** socket into a 4-wire one. I will be splicing into an existing water heater circuit to get the "at least #10" ground that is needed. Kitchen is on the other side of this wall and to the left and that bare ground will be exposed in this garage closet.

Since there's no j-box in the closet, I will need to add one to be able to splice into this circuit.
Do I need to use a whip or a NM Schedule 80 liquid tight conduit?
If so, I would combine it with this j-box:

BUT HOW DO I RUN THE BARE COPPER OUT OF THAT BOX?
[image]

More details about tapping into existing circuit and background to this question:
[Is it possible to add a retorfit ground wire to a (3-wire) Type SE, Style U cable from another branch?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/248564/151179)

Comment: That box is too small.

Answer (score 4):

More like "how do I bring this up to code?"

Random $1 [4x4 steel junction box](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Steel-City-1-Gang-4-in-New-Work-Metal-Electrical-Wall-Box-with-Ground-Bump-521511234GB-50R/206166843). (should be $1, Home Depot is overpriced).

[Cable clamp](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halex-3-8-in-Non-Metallic-NM-Twin-Screw-Cable-Clamp-Connectors-5-Pack-20511/100133208?MERCH=REC-_-pipsem-_-100144257-_-100133208-_-N) appropriate for 10/2 wire.  x2.

["10/3" wire whip.](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-1-2-in-x-6-ft-10-3-Ultra-Whip-Liquidtight-Flexible-Non-Metallic-PVC-Conduit-Cable-Whip-55189407/202210500) (it's like cordage, the /3 counts the ground).  I prefer the kind with a screw-down conduit nut, not a fidgety clip that is "one shot" and you can't easily correct if you do it wrong.

If you don't like the price of wire whip, then feel free to make it using either a) AC/MC cable with appropriate cable clamps for a 1/2" knockout, remember the redheads.  Or b) FMC conduit with appropriate connectors to go in a 1/2" knockout, and THHN wires inside the FMC.  If you have a quality lumberyard who cheerfully sells all that by-the-foot, that's the way to go.

Think about where the stud is.  Choose a knockout on the back of the box that will let the existing Romex come straight in the back.  Install the cable clamp "backwards" there (conduit nut side out, clamp side in, clamp oriented to give you best access to the clamp-down screws).

Bap down the conduit nut with a screwdriver and hammer (what the crowns are for) and thread the Romex through the cable clamp and slide the box down til it hits the wall.  Fasten box to stud with random 1-1/4" deck screws (I prefer Torx or Robertson, but you do you).

Cut the Romex cable so the length coming out of the box is a little less than 12 inches.  Strip at least 6" of sheath off the Romex (leave at least 1/4" past the cable clamp).  Remember to tape/re-mark the white wire as red (any color but green or gray will do, but think "red").

[Little #10-32 machine screw](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-Combo-Thread-Grounding-Screw-Green-10-Pack-G30002-PK10/310741863) goes onto the ground screw on the box.  Romex ground goes around that 180 degrees (little more), tighten down ground screw, leave remaining Romex ground as a pigtail.  By the way, I buy these at a *good* hardware store for 15 cents each either green, or just a silver one out of the screw bin. But shop where you like.

Bare ground wire comes in side knockout via a second cable clamp.

Wire whip comes in another side knockout.  Goes to water heater.

Either a nice huge tan or blue wire nut, or an "accessory ground bar intended for service panels" as a method to splice all these wires together. Crank it to the limits of human strength.

Finally, a [simple blank cover](https://www.homedepot.com/p/RACO-Electrical-Square-Flat-Blank-Cover-8752/100542712) and you're done.

Comment: I don't think the 3/8 in. Non-Metallic (NM) Twin-Screw Cable Clamp be able to hold a bare #6 ground that is only 0.162" What type of clamp did you have in mind?

Comment: This type of ground bar? https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-4-Terminal-Ground-Bar-Kit-for-QO-Homeline-Electrical-Panel-Load-Center-PK4GTACP/100207842

Comment: Is there any concern for the bare ground wire being run so close to the garage sink?

Comment: You don't want the ground "in the sink", but otherwise shouldn't matter much. Remember, ground only carries current in a fault situation. If it were a metal sink, for example, connected to copper pipes then it would actually be connected to your ground all the time.

Comment: @Matt Yeah, a bar like that but I'm used to seeing $3-4. Prices have gone nuts, at least at box stores. Haven't talked to my electrical supplies lately because this is a bad time to do projects so I'm not doing them.  The cable clamp will close tight enough, the 3/8" figure isn't about cable opening, it refers to the size of the knockout... but but it's a weird historical artifact because the KO is actually 1/2" trade size.  Which is 7/8" LOL.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine regarding your comment: "Cut the Romex cable so the length coming out of the box is a little less than 12 inches..." Why 12? Am I supposed to leave almost 6" of the old sheathed Romex in the box and 6" stripped?
Question 2: why are the wires out of my water heater only #12 when it gets power over #10, is it because of longer distance?
Question 3: got the 3 terminal ground bar, they didn't have a 4. What's the best way to connect all these **grounds** together: #6AWG (range) + #10 Romex (to water heater) + #10 (from panel) and the #14 pigtail for the box?

Comment: @Matt to meet Code minima for individual wire length yet Code maxima for wire length in box. You can strip as much Romex as you can reach as long as you leave 1/4" of intact Romex past the clamp. #2 because UL makes them design the appliance to tolerate the higher heat of the smaller wire.  If the hole in the bar can accept a 10-32 screw, bolt the bar directly to the box. Otherwise run one wire *through* the bar and land it on the ground screw.

Comment: Thanks @Harper-ReinstateUkraine that's super helpful!
Another question derived from this project that got upvoted: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/248572/151179